# Using custom delimiters hogan-express and handling {{{ yield }}}

Tags: javascript, express, hogan.js

I'm having a problem figuring this out. I'm trying to use hogan.js (via hogan-express) in a new expressjs application but I also want to use hogan.js in the front-end (where I'll be using Backbone, lodash, etc).

I am using a layout where I have

```
    ...
    {{> header }}
    {{{ yield }}}
    {{> footer }}
    ...
```

And then, by the bottom of the layout I have:

```
    <script type="text/template">
        {{> template }}
    </script>
```

So far those delimited entries are to be handled by hogan-express but the template that gets inserted into that {{> template }} call contains delimited entries. Here's how that looks:

```
    <section>{{name}}</section>
```

And that I need to be ignored by hogan-express so hogan in the front-end handles it.

Now, I don't mind changing the delimiters for hogan-express. I tried that and it works BUT... the using custom delimiters breaks the {{{ yield }}} call. I tried using <% %> as delimiters and changing the yield to be <%{ yield }%> (and various variations of that) but nothing seems to work.

Any idea on how to use custom delimiters in hogan-express without breaking 'yields'?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I hit the same scenario as you.  I could not find an easy solution, so I used a blended one, by combining the ideas of the other suggestions to get it to actually work.  I am using both **hogan-express** and **hogan-express-partials**.

1. Use the suggestion above about `app.locals`

   ```
   app.set('views', config.root + '/server/views');
   app.enable('view cache');
   app.set('view engine', 'html');
   app.locals.delimiters = '<% %>';
   app.set('layout', 'layout');
   app.set('partials', { nav: 'nav', footer: 'footer' });
   app.engine('html', hoganExpress);
   app.use(partials.middleware());
   ```
2. Manually set the `yield` interpolation in your wrapping template. Note that I am temporarily manually switching the delimiters in order to use the defaults.

   ```
   <%> nav %>

   <div class="container">

       <!-- Switch to use original delimiters -->
       <%={{ }}=%>
       {{{ yield }}}

       <!-- Switch back to delimiters that don't conflict with angular -->
       {{=<% %>=}}

   </div>

   <%> footer %>
   ```

It seems to work but I'm not particularly happy with it.  I looked into solutions almost identical to your approaches.  The only other oddity I found in the hogan.js library was that `tripleStash` seemed to also allow for an ampersand (i.e. `&`), but I could not seem to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

to solve this problem in expressjs 4.x i use

```
app.locals.delimiters = '<% %>';
```

just plase this snippet in app.js after

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hjs');
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to set the delimiters Mustache-style in your templates and leave yield alone: https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html#Set-Delimiter

So in your *template*:

```
{{=<% %>=}}
<section><% name %></section>
<%={{ }}=%>
```

This is a little old, but maybe this will help someone else.